# How to convert to give round value using flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I like to know how we can give Math.round value for this using flex.

code:

```
  txtTotal.text=(Number(txtRate.text)*Number(txtQuantity.text)).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code may help you: -

```
txtTotal.text = Math.round(((Number(txtRate.text)*Number(txtQuantity.text))*100)/100).toString();
```